# pandas dataframe dealing with 'list' elements in a nice way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Update: @AntonvBR 's answer worked. Thank you very much!**

Besides, since here I'm dealing with each element in one tea's column, so indeed it's a `Series` rather than a `DataFrame`. Thus I guess `.apply()` works the same as `.map()`.

---

**Original question:**

I'm sorry for not knowing how to express my better, but here is this question:

Say there're **two DataFrames, STUDENT and TEACHER.**

The STUDENT DataFrame has two columns: **ID** and **home**(which city does she or he come from). Of course, the IDs are **unique**.

On the other hand, the TEACHER DataFrame also has two columns: **ID** and **the list of the students' ids** (in their class).

The two are like this:

```
In [72]: stu
Out[72]:
ID home
0   1   XA
1   2   BJ
2   3   TJ
3   4   JN
4   5   CQ
5   6   SH
6   7   GZ
7   8   BJ
8   9   TJ
9  10   BJ

In [75]: tea
Out[75]:
ID            stu
0   1      [1, 2, 3]
1   2   [2, 7, 8, 9]
2   3  [4, 5, 6, 10]
```

And now I want to add a third column on TEACHER, which also contains a list of the teachers' students' **'home'**, and there should be **no duplicate** in each list.

So I wonder how can I do this **in a pandas way**, which looks neat and clean?

I'm new to pandas and SQL, and the only way I come up with is to iterate on each row, and iterate on each list, and fetch the value from another DataFrame and append them one by one...

Please give me some advice or hints.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is quite a trivial problem that could be done in numerous ways. Anyway, 
the fact you have objects inside your `stu` column complicates things a bit.

Consider this example:

```
import pandas as pd

stu = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1,2],
    'home': ['XA','BJ']
})

tea = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1,2],
    'stu': [[1],[1,2]]
})

m = stu.set_index('ID')['home'] # <-- this here creates a map between stu id and stu home
tea['stu_home'] = tea['stu'].apply(lambda x: [m.get(i,'N/A') for i in x])

print(tea)
```

Returns:

```
   ID     stu  stu_home
0   1     [1]      [XA]
1   2  [1, 2]  [XA, BJ]
```

---

**Short explanation:**
The `.apply()` applied on a dataframe column will take all elements and execute a function for each element (which in this case means the row values).
By passing a lambda function the expression becomes really compact.
 We want to find the student home for each element inside each row-element. For this we can use a list-comprehension and fetch values from the dictionary (map) we created in the row above. `m.get(i, 'N/A')` will get each value and return`N/A` if not found. This makes the script a bit more "crash-safe".

Hope this helped you!

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps a lot. The .apply() function also confused me for such a while. With your example, I get to understand its usage. Really appreciated it!